# How to prevent empty response from server

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, http

I'm writing a HTTP file server in C++ for Linux. It's using sockets, have 8 worker threads, it's using select to only handle ready sockets. I am currently limited to a personal internet connection, while developing. In general it's working perfectly, but when I request a lot of larger files concurrently (ex. 50 files of 10 MB) a few of them just closes and returns an empty response. Any ideas of to why? Can something be done to prevent this?

Comment: You need to post your code so we can have any hope of figuring out what's wrong with it.

Comment: It's currently a very large project, so instead of dumping a lot of pages of code, I am looking for more general insigts to why a socket would drop a connection and strategies to prevent it. If the answer is, it wouldn't drop a connection, then that's a great answer as well.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you're running into the TCP backlog limit, and it can't keep up with all the requests. See http://veithen.github.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html. Try increasing the backlog argument to `listen()`.

Comment: I had the limit on 100, which should be enough. Tried changing it to 500 with the same result. Do you know of any way I can see why it's dropping connections?

Comment: make sure the 1st arg to select() is growing to the max fds open, probably over 100 if you have 50 connections + 50 files open in one process.

Comment: The first arg of select is set to highest fd (value, not count) + 1 as the manual descripes. Before calling select I build up the 3 fd sets and at the same time find the highes fd.

Comment: Run it under a debugger and set breakpoints at the places where it calls `close()` on the socket.

Comment: Perhaps you have a rate-limit set in the local firewall to avoid denial-of-service attacks. Do the failing clients timeout or get icmp or rst replies?

Comment: @Barmar - Already did that, but it never calls close, that's what I don't understand.

Comment: Add some logging of the IP/port numbers, so you can see if the connections that are dropped are ever returned by `accept()`.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses. I've spend a few days trying to figure this out, and it seems it's the clients who resets the connection. Could it be that browsers resets connections if there's long between responses?